# wget to download multiple folders from https url

Tags: shell, for-loop, wget

I am using following line of wget to download dataset.

```
wget -e robots=off -m -np -R .html,.tmp -nH --cut-dirs=3 \
                 https://ladsweb.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/archive/orders/50672578/ \
                 --header "Authorization: Bearer <your appKey>" -P <target dir>
```

Now, I want to download multiple folders from same URL (i.e. https://ladsweb.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/archive/orders/50672578/; https://ladsweb.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/archive/orders/50672579/; https://ladsweb.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/archive/orders/50672580/ etc)

I am using for loop in shell script for a same as following:

```
for i in 50672578 50672579 50672580 
do
    wget -e robots=off -m -np -R .html,.tmp -nH --cut-dirs=3 \
                 https://ladsweb.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/archive/orders/$i/ \
                 --header "Authorization: Bearer <your appKey>" -P <target dir> 
done
```

But this gives me the following error:

> Proxy request sent, awaiting a response... 400 Bad Request
>       2018-11-12 12:18:34 ERROR 400: Bad Request.

Individually it is working fine but not via for-loop.

Kindly request to indicate my mistakes.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you run `wget` with "-v" and post the output here?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use a for loop you can express the list of urls as follows:

`https://ladsweb.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/archive/orders/{50672578,50672579,50672580}/`

Answer (score 0):

Can you assign URL's in array like below and read them in for loop

ARRAY=(URL1 URL2... URLN)